# Declaring more than 1 pointer in a single declaration

Tags: c++

Reading accelearated C++: theres a discussion on whether `int* i` or `int *i` should be used. And that `int* p, q` is actually `int (*p), q`. So I suppose `q` is just an int? (not a pointer)? Then is it possible to declare a bunch of pointers?

I don't suppose `int *p, *q` will work?

Comment: You should maybe read the part that recommends "int* p; int q;" a paragraph later

Comment: Why don't you just use two separate lines if you are not sure what the outcome is? Keep it simple. Keep it how you understand it.

Comment: I'd also suggest that for something this trivial, test it before asking

Comment: @stefan - sure, plus it's easier to comment the vars later.  Why do some developers obsess over such trivia - is there a sudden shortage of real bugs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I don't suppose int *p, *q will work?

It will, test it. That's **correct way to do this**.

Another option, to avoid such confusion, is to declare them separately

```
int* p;
int* q;
```

---

> So I suppose q is just an int

in `int* p, q` - yes, it *is* `int`, and *not* a pointer.

Comment: It's not exactly **the** correct way, it is just a possible way. Much better is to declare each object separately, and avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: @BoPersson - true. Point taken (I actually had doubts if I should put "the" in my answer :) )

Comment: It's "the" way, if one insists on "one line, one semicolon". Since the question is only about this style, the use of "the" is appropriate, imho.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename T> using ptr = T*;

ptr<int> p, q;
```